# How to remove lines made with a PostGIS query automatically if origin is not in the map window?

Tags: qgis, postgis, labeling, query

I have a PostGIS point layer with labels. I moved these points because they were too close.

To connect label and point, I created a line vector layer which was made with a query in the DB-Manager (see below).

If a point is not visible because it's outside of the QGIS window, but the label is still inside, the label is not visible anymore. But, unfortunately, these lines are still visible. What do I have to add to the query to enable these lines if their origin is not visible?

Query:

`SELECT
  id,
  ST_Makeline(St_setSRID((geom),2056), St_setSRID(St_Point("X"::numeric, "Y"::numeric),2056)) as "geom"
FROM
"database"."table"
WHERE
  "X" IS NOT NULL AND
  "Y" IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Is geom already a linestring? Have you tried ST_AddPoint(geom, ST_MakePoint(x, y))?

Comment: @JohnBarça..no. Instead of ST_Makeline or where should I add it? thx!